# How to add the current String in the previous tableview from UIAlertAction in objective c

Tags: objective-c, tableview, uialertcontroller

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show the String in the previous Tableview cell in the same UIViewController

As shown in Image

[image]

When I click on ok I want to add full instead of label

[image]

When I am adding string in cellforrowatindexpath it get replace in all tableview cell. I want to replace label text according to selected index.
My code is look like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(tableView == customaudittable)
    {
        static NSString *STI=@"STI";
        AuditTableViewCell *cell = (AuditTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AuditTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        cell.audittitlelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.auditdesclbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[namearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return cell;
    }
    if(tableView == FPNtable)
    {
        static NSString *STI=@"STI";
        FPNTableViewCell *cell = (FPNTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FPNTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        cell.fulllbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarrayFPN objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        return cell;
    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if(tableView == Audittable)
    {
        NSString *listString;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        listString = [defaults objectForKey:@"ListString"];

         AuditTableViewCell *cell = (AuditTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

         cell.listlbl.text=listString;


        midString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[midarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self serverconnectionFPN];

      //  Audittable.alpha=0.24;

        UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
        CGRect rect;
        if (idarrayFPN.count < 4) {
            rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 160);
            [controller setPreferredContentSize:rect.size];

        }
        else if (idarrayFPN.count < 6){
            rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 300);
            [controller setPreferredContentSize:rect.size];
        }
        else if (idarrayFPN.count < 8){
            rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 200);
            [controller setPreferredContentSize:rect.size];

        }
        else {
            rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 250);
            [controller setPreferredContentSize:rect.size];
        }

        alert =
        [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AuditCheckList"
                                            message:@""
                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        FPNTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        FPNTable.delegate = self;
        FPNTable.dataSource = self;
        [controller.view addSubview:FPNTable];
        [controller.view bringSubviewToFront:FPNTable];
        [controller.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [FPNTable setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [FPNTable setAllowsSelection:YES];

        [alert setValue:controller forKey:@"contentViewController"];

        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

            [Audittable reloadData];
        }];
        [alert addAction:cancelAction];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

     if (tableView == FPNTable) {
        FPNTableViewCell *cell = (FPNTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.circleimg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleClick.png"];

         NSString *ListString;
         ListString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarrayFPN objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         NSLog(@"List Item =%@",ListString);
         NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         [defaults setObject:ListString forKey:@"ListString"];

    }

}
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FPNTableViewCell *cell = (FPNTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.circleimg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circleicon.png"];

}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

haven't got the time to read all your code, but I guess that your question is understood, what you can do which is the easiest way, is that when the user selects the option from the UIAlertAction, you can save that option in a **global string** in the class, then assign the "Label" **UILabel** to that **global string**, finally you need to reload your **UITableView**

I hope that helps

Comment: But I am confuse in which tableview method?

Comment: when I am setting it in cellforrowatindexpath its value set in all cell.I want to set it only cell which I have Selected.